# How to disable a button in VueJS to avoid redundant route navigation? Conditional click events possible?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I have a `Home` button in the app I am working on and want to stop to the error from being thrown when someone clicks on `Home` when they are already there. The error I get right now is

```
Error in v-on handler (Promise/async): "NavigationDuplicated: Avoided redundant navigation to current location: "/"."
```

And presently my tag looks like this in code:

```
<img @click="$router.push({ path: '/' })" src="/svgs/home.svg" class="home-btn" />
```

Is there anyway to have a conditional statement with a click event? V-if doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways you can do that. If you are using `<button>`, then you can simply disable it using the condition by checking your current route.

Since, you are using the `<img />` element (As per standards, `disabled` attribute is not available for `img` tag), you will have to handle that using additional condition in the handler.

```
// If using named views
function clickHandler() {
  if (this.$route.name !== 'home') {
    this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
  }
}

// If not using named views
function clickHandler() {
  if (this.$route.path !== '/') {
    this.$router.push({ path: '/' });
  }
}
```

Use the above handler for your `<img />` element as:

```
<img @click="clickHandler" src="/svgs/home.svg" class="home-btn" />
```

> On a side note, from accessibility point of view, consider using `button` or `a` element and wrap your image inside it. If not that, at least add `tabindex` to your `img` tag.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed breakdown! I'm still new and want to get into the habit of always coding with accessibility in mind, so that point was fantastic insight. Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you can just disable the button by checking the current path using `$route`

see documentation - https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object